# Suggestions for app background

Tags: icon

I am designing an app background for learners of the English language. Normally, I design icons, but I decided to try putting together an app, iphone, android, ect, ect, where the learner is presented with a set of icons each icon representing an idea or object. I attached a draft of the background here and I would like suggestions on what I can do to make this background more professional and stand out. What can I do to improve it?  [image: US flag with square place markers for the icons and text, 8 total]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please take a look at our [requirements for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611) and [edit] your question accordingly, lest it be closed.

Comment: Two point immediately come to mind. I'd go for a background that stands out a bit *less*, not (even) *more*. Also, most references to English-the-language makes use of the Britsh flag  and not the American. See just about any website which offers multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion get rid of the flag. The British flag may be better but it can create confusion as some words are spelled differently in American English. I'd say a solid fill perhaps a dark blue similar to the American and British flag blues. Perhaps if you're an illustrator you can create a minimalist illustration of a classroom in the background but fade it so it's not distracting.

Comment: So, based on the answers I've gotten here, I'll do this: As per user5854648, I will create a background of a classroom with both the British and US flags to represent both of the English languages. I greatly appreciate the answers!

Comment: @DanielBaker Ah, Yes, by all means ignore the advice you sought here and got. Insofar as a background goes, less is more. Backgrounds are called such because they recede into the *background.* Go figure. ; )